# Return an empty enumerable instead of getting nullReferenceException still throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net

I see the GetById function is returning null in this forEach which is throwing an exception, to prevent this I tried returning an empty Enumerable of that same type however I still get the `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
foreach (var categoryEntry in menus.GetById(options.OnlineOrdering.MenuId).Categories.OrderBy(i => i.Position) ?? Enumerable.Empty<MenuMenuCategory>())
```

Comment: There are a lot of places on this one line of code which *could* throw a `NullReferenceException`.  Which one is it?

Comment: It's the GetById function returning null, I'll add that to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accounting for the wrong null checking.  If this is returning `null`:

```
menus.GetById(options.OnlineOrdering.MenuId)
```

Then this is throwing the error:

```
menus.GetById(options.OnlineOrdering.MenuId).Categories
```

Since you already have a null-coalescing check, you can use a null-conditional check on the expression that's failing:

```
menus.GetById(options.OnlineOrdering.MenuId)?.Categories
```

This would cause the entire expression to evaluate to `null` (never even trying to dereference the `Categories` property) is `GetById()` returns `null`.  The result of that expression would then trigger the null-coalescing check you've added, and the loop should successfully iterate zero times as you intend.

Comment: `options.OnlineOrdering` and `options.OnlineOrdering.MenuId` could also return null

Comment: @Charlieface: True.  But so could options, so could Menus, so could Categories, etc.  Checking *everything* for null becomes overkill fast though.  If there’s that much potential for null references then the domain is pretty much out of control.  It’ll be up to the OP to find the right balance.